# Grep by all filenames in a directory

Tags: unix, grep, ps

I want to get the process status for all services running in a given directory. Right now I can check one by one `ps -ef | grep ServiceName`. But is there a way to `ls` the directory and `ps` every service?

Something like `ps -ef | grep < ls`?

Comment: are you looking for `ps -ef | grep "$(ls)"` ?

Comment: @incBrain Exactly Thanks! Throw up an answer if you want cred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already posted it as a comment, this should do what you want:

```
ps -ef | grep "$(ls)"
```

Answer (score 2):

In Bash:

```
ps -ef | grep "$(ls)"
```

(The same line appeared in incBrain's comment while I was composing and testing the rest of my answer in Debian/Bash.)

It will generate garbage if the pattern appears in `ps` output as a command line argument (not the command) or as a part of the command. To reduce this I would use `find` instead of `ls` to obtain full path:

```
ps -ef | grep -f <(find -L "$(pwd)" -maxdepth 1 -type f)
```

Still there may be some unwanted extra output.

Note that these are not

> services running in a given directory

rather *processes with executables in a given directory*.

To tell current working directory of a process you may read `/proc/<PID>/cwd`. Next example is (quick and dirty) `ps` alternative and it shows that you can extract information from `/proc` in a form you want:

```
sudo bash -c 'for i in /proc/[1-9]* ; do PID=$(basename "$i"); E=$(readlink "${i}/exe"); D=$(readlink "${i}/cwd"); echo -e "PID=${PID}\tEXE=${E}\tCWD=${D}" ; done | grep "CWD=$(pwd)$"'
```

You need `sudo` to get access to all processes. If this isn't necessary and you want to run it as regular user, the part within `'` delimiters is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
processes="$(ps -ef)"
for file in *;do
  grep "$file" <<<"$processes"
done
```